# Rsync interrupted by "No space left" message

Tags: rsync

Say I want to `rsync` /dir of a remote host to the /dir (same path) of a local host. For that I would do `rsync -artz root@remote-host:/dir/* /dir/` from my local host. The /dir on the remote host contains the following when I perform an ls -la /dir:

```
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Mar 15 20:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4096 Feb 17 22:42 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Feb 18 00:33 some_dir
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Mar 15 20:50 other_dir
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Feb 18 00:38 a_dir
```

The problem is that when I did the `rsync` I did not notice that I did not have enough space left on the /dir of my local host, and so I ended up with the following error message:

```
rsync: write failed on "/dir/a_dir/another_dir/some_file": No space left on device
```

My question is, since during the `rsync` the /dir on my local host got full I'd like to know if it was only the `a_dir` that did not made a full rsync. Are the other directories (`some_dir` and `other_dir`) ok?

Comment: what is your sorting order ? how can you get `some_dir` before `a_dir`  in `ls -al above` ?

Answer (score 0):

You started with `rsync -artz root@remote-host:/dir/* /dir/`

So in your scenario you can check if `some_dir` transfered correctly with `rsync -artz root@remote-host:/dir/some_dir /dir/` (note the lack of a trailing `/` on the source path).

If you get no errors then that directory tree has already completely transferred.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the ":" in the rsync command. Just fixed the post

Comment: what is the expected output in case `some_dir` transfered correctly?

Comment: @bulvgo_uh you'll get no errors if everything has already transferred successfully.